# Canonical URLs and Google

Tags: seo, google-search

As far as Google and canonical URLs go - is there any advantage to adding a 301 redirect from:

http://www.mydomain.com/index.php

to

http://www.mydomain.com/

Comment: how about a `canonical` meta-tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No the default page to open when no page name is specified is either "`index.html`" or "`index.php`", with the priority given to the latter by default. So there will not be any advantage as such & moreover, it's not needed.

For any other page (except the Home page or the "`index`" named pages), if you specify the Redirect Header 301, then you are notifying Google & other search engines to store the target URL as the active & the latest one (not the first one), in their database. It's like setting a permalink in the databases of the search engines with your latest active URLs.

There will be one **big** advantage, however. When you are specifying "`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php`", you are notifying search engines to load the "`index.php`" page only all the times. However, if you just specify "`http://www.mydomain.com/`" to the search engines, then it's upto the (`mydomain.com`) server's interpretation (after understanding that server's HTAccess rules & other Redirection rules, if any) to show the user the correct file - it may be "`index.php`" (first priority), or "`index.html`", or "`index.htm`" - although that correct file may or may not be present in that server's hosting space.
If the correct file is not present, then a 404 Not Found page is shown. And it's the responsibility of the owner of that server to have the correct file in his server's root folder, so that never a 404 Not Found page is shown to any user.

**So I will say that it's a big advantage mentioning "`http://www.mydomain.com/`" instead of "`http://www.mydomain.com/index.php`".**

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry - just for clarification, do you mean it's a big advantage to REDIRECT from index.php to / ?

Comment: @Mark - If your main "`index`" file has the probability to change with regards to its extension (or even with regards to its name - like "`main.php`" instead of "`index.php`"), then I will definitely recommend you to go with the redirection. Otherwise, it's best to have it as it is, with no 404 Error, because every redirection adds page-loading time, which should be minimized as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any advantage of using a redirect..for one thing, it will add loading time to your page, and Google also ranks pages according to speed.